# Extract substrings from a list of patterns in Python

Tags: python, string, extract

I have a list of patterns that contains the Page ID of my webpage

```
patterns = [
           https://www.my-website.com/articles/$1/show,
           https://www.my-website.com/groups/$1/articles/$2,
           https://www.my-website.com/blogs/$1/show,
           https://www.my-website.com/groups/$1/documents/$2
]
```

where $1 is the Page ID for the first list item, and $2 is the Page ID for the second list item, and so on.

I have an input WebURL string and I want to extract the Page ID from this string

```
input = https://www.my-website.com/articles/asojd1277/show
output = asojd1277

input = https://www.my-website.com/groups/hsaid123/articles/hqwoj8239
output = hqwoj8239
```

Is there any python library that does this for me? I tried the **re.match** (regex package) function but it does not fit into my case.

Comment: You should also post an example of your code, especially the part where you say that `re.match` does not fit your case.

Answer (score 0):

You could update your patterns to use `(\w+)` to capture a sequence of word characters. Then `re.match` can be used.

For example:

```py
re.match(r'https://www.my-website.com/groups/(\w+)/articles/(\w+)', 
          'https://www.my-website.com/groups/hsaid123/articles/hqwoj8239').groups()
# ('hsaid123', 'hqwoj8239')
```

Answer (score 0):

I obtained exactly what you asked using `re.match`:

```py
import re
from typing import List

patterns: List = [
    r"https://www.my-website.com/articles/(\w+)/show",
    r"https://www.my-website.com/groups/(\w+)/articles/(\w+)",
    r"https://www.my-website.com/blogs/(\w+)/show",
    r"https://www.my-website.com/groups/(\w+)/documents/(\w+)"
]

inputs = [
    "https://www.my-website.com/articles/asojd1277/show",
    "https://www.my-website.com/groups/hsaid123/articles/hqwoj8239"
]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for inp in inputs:
        for pattern in patterns:
            result = re.match(pattern, inp)
            if result is not None:
                print(result.groups())
```

This returns

```
('asojd1277',)
('hsaid123', 'hqwoj8239')
```

From this you should be able to choose which element to take/keep.